# How to clear textinputs by button from another page in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

My problem is probably mainly because of lack of skills but i couldnt find any similar posts. So I have textinputs on mainscreen. I need to have button in secondscreen which clear these textinputs.

I couldnt figure out how to can i call the clear_inputs method and pass textinput as arguments. I think with this clear_inputs method i could empty those textfields, but how to bind it to that button in another page?

Py.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty






class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def clear_inputs(self, text_inputs):
        for text_input in text_inputs:
            text_input.text = ''

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def changescreen(self, value):

        try:
            if value !='main':
                self.current = value
        except:
            print('No Screen named'+ value)




class testiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Hello'



testiApp().run()
```

KV.

```
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
        name:'Main'
    SecondScreen:
        name:'Page2'



<MainScreen>:
    name:'Main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text:'testfield1'
            TextInput:
                id: textfield1
            Label:
                text:'testfield2'
            TextInput:
                id: textfield2

        Button:
            text:'Next Page'
            on_release: app.root.current ='Page2'




<SecondScreen>:
    name:'Page2'
    Button:
        text:'Clear textfields'
        on_release:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following enhancements (kv file & Python script) are required to clear the `TextInput`'s text in another screen.

### kv file

- In order to access the `TextInput` widgets, add an `id: container` to the instantiated object, `GridLayout:`
- Each screen has by default a property `manager` that gives you the instance of the [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage) used.
- Bind the `on_release` event to method, `clear_inputs()` without any argument

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<MainScreen>:
    name:'Main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        GridLayout:
            id: container
            ...

        Button:
            text:'Next Page'
            on_release: root.manager.current ='Page2'


<SecondScreen>:
    name:'Page2'
    Button:
        text:'Clear textfields'
        on_release: root.clear_inputs()
```

### Py file

- Add import statement, `from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput`
- Use `ScreenManager`'s `get_screen('Main')` function to get the instantiated object, `MainScreen`
- Use `for` loop to traverse the children of `GridLayout:` via `ids.container`
- Use `isinstance()` function to check for `TextInput` widget

#### Snippets - Py file

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
...
class SecondScreen(Screen):

    def clear_inputs(self):
        main = self.manager.get_screen('Main')
        for child in reversed(main.ids.container.children):
            if isinstance(child, TextInput):
                child.text = ''
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks again this seems working. Btw how would you make it work if there would be other layouts in same page which textfields would need to empty also? i tried some tests not worth mention but couldnt make it work.

Comment: Are you referring to two or more container in `MainScreen` whereby the TextInput's text needs to be clear?

Comment: Hi Ikolim. Yes indeed im referring to that. How would you do that?

Comment: Assuming that the container's `ids` are `box1`, and `box2`, add `for` loop for each of the containers. e.g. `for child in reversed(main.ids.box1.children):`

Comment: Thanks! it will take some time to make my mind think like coder :P So simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm undestanding correctly, what you want to do is use a button in page X (`Main`?) to change the text in page Y (`Page2`?). I'm not an expert on Kivy, so there might be a better way, but here are a few thoughts:

1) I tried giving a class attribute `parent` to all screens, which turned out to be a bad idea because the name was already in used by Kivy. You could simply change it to `parent_` or something and give it a go yourself. What you want is to pass the "parent" as a parameter to `__init__` on creation:

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, children_, **kwargs):
        # you might need to save the children too
        self.children_ = children_

    def add_child(self, child):
        # maybe as dict
        self.children_[child.name] = child


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, parent_, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # maybe the screen manager or the main app?
        self.parent_ = parent_
        self.name_ = "Second"
    ....
    def clear_inputs(self, text_inputs):
        ....

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, parent_, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # maybe the screen manager or the main app?
        self.parent_ = parent_
        # you may want to 
    ....
        # Get the appropriate screen from the parent
        self.parent_.children_["Second"].clear_inputs(...)
```

2) I also saw another way from a [youtube tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/screen-manager-pages-screens-kivy-application-python-tutorial/). Instead of running your app directly, assign it to a variable and reference that variable. This might still need tampering for advanced usecases:

```
# Use the global variable within your classes/methods
class Whatever:
    def whatever2(self, params):
        app.something() 

....

app = testiApp()
app.run()
```